# How to search by date range in cassandra?

Tags: php, cassandra, cql

for e.g

```
SELECT *
FROM api_call_log
WHERE account_sid='XXXXXXXXXXXX'            AND 
      created_time >= 01-02-2016 00:00:00   AND
      created_time <= 31-02-2016 23:59:59
ALLOW FILTERING
```

I am getting records from first month as well though I searched for second month.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without seeing your table structure or relevant portions of your result set.  But I did notice that you are *not* specifying a GMT offset, which means you are effectively ***querying by your default local offset***.  The problem, is that Cassandra stores by GMT+0000.

For example, if you have a negative GMT offset of say -0600 (like me), a query for GMT-0600 would miss 6-hours-worth of data from February 1st.  For instance, if I have a row out there for `2016-02-01 01:00:00+0000`, this query will not return it:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm events WHERe monthbucket='201602' 
    AND eventdate >= '2016-02-01 00:00:00';

 monthbucket | eventdate | beginend | eventid | eventname
-------------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------

(0 rows)
```

And that's because `2016-02-01 01:00:00+0000` is essentially `2016-01-31 19:00:00-0600`.  So if I add the GMT offset of `0000`, I see the row.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm events WHERe monthbucket='201602'
    AND eventdate >= '2016-02-01 00:00:00+0000';

 monthbucket | eventdate                | beginend | eventid                              | eventname
-------------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+-------------------
      201602 | 2016-02-01 01:00:00+0000 |        b | 78d2c2b7-c4ec-408f-be37-eccc0c05727d | test month border

(1 rows)
```

My guess, is that you probably have the opposite problem (extra rows vs. missing rows) due to having a *positive* GMT offset.  Not specifying your offset in your query could be why it is including rows from the previous month.  And if that's the case, then you may want those rows.

Also, don't use `ALLOW FILTERING`.  Like ever.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM api_call_log WHERE account_sid='XXXXXXXXXXXX' AND jobs.created_at between '01-02-2016 00:00:00' and '31-02-2016 23:59:59';
```

And also check the DATE/TIME format of the date column

Comment: `between` does not work for Cassandra.  I think the OP accidentally included the mysql tag.